# How to get dynamically created elements using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated

I am writing a javascript code to automate simple actions on my organization's admin console page (code is going to work in the dev tools console so I can only use pure javascript).

[image: visual of the site]

Actions are simple, I click on "details" (number 1 on image) and then click on "statistics" (number 3 on image).

The problem is that sectors 2 and 3 (see the image please) do not exist before I click sector 1.
After I click sector 1 with the javascript click() command sectors 2,3 are created but I can not find them with javascript.

I tried getting them with id and with class, but none of them works.

I have tried searching for answers but I only get answers for the situation where people can find dynamically created elements but can not use functions on it, my case is different, I can not find them at all.

This are the elements that are dynamically created:

```
    <tr id="__BVID__54__details_0_" role="row" class="b-table-details">
   <td colspan="16" role="cell">
      <div class="tabs promotions-menu-tabs row" id="__BVID__350">
         <!---->
         <div class="col-auto">
            <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="__BVID__350__BV_tab_controls_">
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="1" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link active" id="__BVID__351___BV_tab_button__">Properties</a></li>
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="2" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link" id="__BVID__354___BV_tab_button__">Prizes</a></li>
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="3" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link" id="__BVID__356___BV_tab_button__">Stats</a></li>
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="4" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link" id="__BVID__358___BV_tab_button__">Balance</a></li>
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="5" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link" id="__BVID__360___BV_tab_button__">Balance journal</a></li>
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="6" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link" id="__BVID__362___BV_tab_button__">Journal</a></li>
               <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="7" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link" id="__BVID__364___BV_tab_button__">Statistics</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-content col" id="__BVID__350__BV_tab_container_">
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" class="tab-pane active" tabindex="-1" id="__BVID__351" aria-labelledby="__BVID__351___BV_tab_button__" style="">
               <div data-v-75a75998="" class="promotions-properties">
                  <div data-v-75a75998="">
                     <div class="prompt_content mb-4 break-all">
                        <!---->
                        <div class="mb-4">
                           <h4>Leaderboard properties</h4>
                           <div class="mb-1"><b>Places in list:</b> range to 1000000 
                           </div>
                           <div class="mb-1"><b>Points limits:</b> values 1
                           </div>
                           <div class="mb-1"><b>Amount factor:</b> values &gt;0:20
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-4">
                           <h4>Customer filters</h4>
                           <div class="mb-1"><b>Segment:</b> test promotions segment
                           </div>
                           <div class="mb-1"><b>Customer verification status:</b> ACCEPTED
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!---->
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="tab-pane" id="__BVID__354" aria-labelledby="__BVID__354___BV_tab_button__" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="tab-pane" id="__BVID__356" aria-labelledby="__BVID__356___BV_tab_button__" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="tab-pane" id="__BVID__358" aria-labelledby="__BVID__358___BV_tab_button__" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="tab-pane" id="__BVID__360" aria-labelledby="__BVID__360___BV_tab_button__" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="tab-pane" id="__BVID__362" aria-labelledby="__BVID__362___BV_tab_button__" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="tab-pane" id="__BVID__364" aria-labelledby="__BVID__364___BV_tab_button__" style="display: none;"></div>
            <!---->
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Any help is appreciated.

This is my javascript code:

```
let promoIdsToCheck = [230];

let promoTable = document.getElementsByClassName("table b-table table-sm border b-table-stacked-md")[0];
let promoTableBody = promoTable.tBodies[0];
let promoTableBodyRows = promoTableBody.rows;

console.log(promoTableBodyRows.length)

for(let i = 1; i < promoTableBodyRows.length; i++){
    if(promoIdsToCheck.includes(parseInt(promoTableBodyRows[i].firstChild.textContent))){
        let detailsDiv = promoTableBodyRows[i].lastChild;
        let detailsButton = detailsDiv.children[0].children[0].children[0];

        detailsButton.click();

        let smt = document.getElementsByClassName("col-auto")[0]; // this is undefined
        console.log(smt);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using JS to solve this issue? You haven't provided any code.

Comment: I provided it now, you can see it. Thanks.